# Apparent conflict between bundler and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rvm, bundler

I'm using rvm with a gemset for a rails project. Normally, installed gems get put in to the my_gemset/gems folder, however it seems that gems sourced from github get put in to my_gemset/bundler/gems. However, because there's a file with the name bundler in the gemset folder, Bundler throws an error:

> Bundler could not install a gem because it needs to create a
>   directory, but a file exists -
>   /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@my_gemset/bundler. Please delete this
>   file and try again.

Renaming the file allows the bundle install command to complete successfully, so I'm pretty confident the problem is just isolated to this one file. I don't understand Bundler well enough to just go deleting the file though, because it looks like it's doing important stuff.

Can I just delete the file without bad stuff happening? Is there a way to change the directory that gems sourced from github get installed to?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like these file are binstubs that somehow got installed in to the main gemset folder, with duplicates installed to the gemset/bin folder. So probably not necessary to keep? Will be renaming for now.